# compound model name problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails 3 app I'm making, I have a model called homeBase. 
The class names for this (controller/model) are homeBase for both - not pluralized for the controller. Yet the file names were made home_base_controller and home_base.rb
I'm having a very tough time getting the pathing to work for this and other models with a compound name. Every time I try to use the controller, I'm told it's uninitialized. 
Are there some black magic rules for using compound words as names in rails?

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not following the usual naming scheme?

Comment: Ive redone things with what I believe is the scheme rails demands - model HomeBase (home_base) and controller HomeBases (home_bases). However, I can't get pathing right either. new_home_base_path fails. How would I refer to a path then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Rails is an opinionated framework and has specific opinions on how these things should be dealt with. Here  is a sampling of relevant Rails conventions:

Class (model) names are singular, capitalized camel case. In your case, the model should be called `HomeBase`.

Controllers (being ruby classes themselves) are also defined as capitalized camel case, but the referenced model is plural. In your case, the controller should be called `HomeBasesController`.

File names always use lowercase, underscored notation. In your case, the file holding `class HomeBase < ActiveRecord::Base` should be in `app/models/home_base.rb` and the file holding `class HomeBasesController < ApplicationController` should be in `app/controllers/home_bases_controller.rb`